# How to find where is the broken in the house electric wire?

Tags: electrical

I have a complex wiring problem. one of my outside house light is not working and I took out the light and found that the hot wire ( black) is not getting power. All other lights and appliances are working in the house except this light. I also check breaker box and it seems to all good and getting power so it is broken it between somewhere. I cannot see where are these wires coming from or connected? I tried hard I cannot locate any junction box near by. obviously the wire is broken but do not know how do I find where is broken because I do not know where is this connected to in other end? it is going through cement wall  so it is not east to break and look at the wire connection? Any help is appreciated?

Comment: You could check to see if you have any GFI's that may have tripped. Check your garage.

Comment: The easiest solution is a wire tracer, which transmitted a signal into the dead circuit and let's you use a receiver to follow it through the walls; where it stops is the disconnection point. They aren't cheap, though, unless you get lucky on eBay. Cheap check: is power teaching the switch? Are you sure the switch hasn't failed?

Answer (score 1):

My most valuable tool is thinking about what the last guy did.  Or was most likely to have done.  I see lots of "what were you thinking?" situations but later I learn something else, and go "Oh, that's what he was thinking."

OK the wire goes through the cement wall. Somebody had to install that wire the first time. Where would he have routed it?  What would've been easiest for him?

Do you have more than one outside light?  Is it possible this light is fed from one of the others?